# setting up the stack and heap in Unicorn emulator in C

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to learn x86 assembly using the Unicorn emulator, everything goes fine until I try using push or pop, I've searched the web for tutorials but I could'nt find anything useful that deals with the stack. I get this error when I try to use push or pop "Failed on uc_emu_start() with error returned 7: Invalid memory write (UC_ERR_WRITE_UNMAPPED)".

```
#include <unicorn/unicorn.h>

// code to be emulated
#define X86_CODE32 "\xB9\x05\x00\x00\x00\x51\x5A" 

// memory address where emulation starts
#define ADDRESS 0x600000
//#define ADDRESS_STC 0x100000
#define ADDRESS_STC 0x6000000 

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
 uc_engine *uc;
 //uc_engine *uc0;
 uc_err err;
 uc_err err0;
 //int r_ecx = 0x1234;     // ECX register
 int r_ecx;     // ECX register
 int r_edx;     // EDX register
 int r_esp;     
 int r_esp0 = 0x7FFFFF;     


 printf("Emulate i386 code\n");

 // Initialize emulator in X86-32bit mode
 err = uc_open(UC_ARCH_X86, UC_MODE_32, &uc);
 if (err != UC_ERR_OK) {
 printf("Failed on uc_open() with error returned: %u\n", err);
 return -1;
 }

 // map 2MB memory for this emulation
 uc_mem_map(uc, ADDRESS, 1 * 1024 * 1024, UC_PROT_ALL);
 //uc_mem_map(uc, ADDRESS_STC, 2 * 1024 * 1024, UC_PROT_ALL);
 printf("Mike \n");

 // write machine code to be emulated to memory
 if (uc_mem_write(uc, ADDRESS, X86_CODE32, sizeof(X86_CODE32) - 1)) {
 printf("Failed to write emulation code to memory, quit!\n");
 return -1;
  }
  printf("Mike 0\n");

   // initialize machine registers

  uc_reg_write(uc,UC_X86_REG_EBP, &r_esp0+512);
  uc_reg_write(uc,UC_X86_REG_ESP, &r_esp0+512);

  printf("Mike 01\n");

  // emulate code in infinite time & unlimited instructions
  err=uc_emu_start(uc, ADDRESS, ADDRESS + sizeof(X86_CODE32) - 1, 0, 0);
if (err) {
 printf("Failed on uc_emu_start() with error returned %u: %s\n",
   err, uc_strerror(err));
   uc_reg_read(uc,UC_X86_REG_RSP,&r_esp0);
   printf("esp0 0x%x\n",r_esp0);
 }

 // now print out some registers
 printf("Emulation done. Below is the CPU context\n");

 uc_reg_read(uc, UC_X86_REG_ECX, &r_ecx);
 uc_reg_read(uc, UC_X86_REG_EBP, &r_edx);
 uc_reg_read(uc, UC_X86_REG_ESP, &r_esp);

 printf(">>> EX = 0x%x\n", r_ecx);
 printf(">>> EDX = 0x%x\n", r_edx);
 printf(">>> ESP = 0x%x\n", r_esp);


 uc_close(uc);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The `unicorn`-tag is not about whatever your "unicorn" is.

Answer (score 2):

ESP is set to 0x600, but memory is mapped starting at 0x400000.

Comment: this is going to sound stupid but where should I move the memory or where I should I move the ESP? should it be moved to the mapped memory?

Comment: That’s completely dependent on what code you’re planning to run in the emulator. Right now you’re only using 400000 - 400006, so you can put the stack pretty much anywhere. Try setting ESP to 410000.

Comment: If you’re going to start using serious code, you may want separate mappings for code and data, so that code can be read-only and data can be non-executable. So then data and stack might be at 0x600000 - 0x7FFFFF.

Comment: btw, do I setup the stack using "uc_reg_write(uc,UC_X86_REG_ESP, &r_esp0+512);" or is done another way?

Comment: You made so many changes! I suggest you go back to your original program, and simply change `uc_reg_write(uc,UC_X86_REG_RSP, 1024+512);` to `uc_reg_write(uc,UC_X86_REG_RSP, 0x410000);`

Comment: Great! Now you can go ahead and make the other changes, if you want, but implement and test each change one at a time.